# Cannot read PDF input using iText7 with .NET Core 6.0

Tags: pdf, itext, itext7

I am trying to read a PDF using iText 7.1.15 with .Net Core 6.0
Some of the data is getting back as it should and I am able to read it, but some of the data is getting back as unreadable text (gibrish).

When I do copy/paste to the readable data - it works perfectly. I can copy the data to a document and read it, but when I do the same for the unreadable data - it is not readable even in copy/paste.

Unfortunately, I cannot export the PDF again. I am getting it from an outer source and cannot change it.

Is there any option I can read the data?

Thank you,
Yaniv

Comment: There are multiple possible reasons why iText cannot extract the text data correctly from a PDF. Thus, please share the PDF in question for analysis. Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: @mkl Unfortunately, it contains sensitive data and I cannot share it publicly. May I send it over via email for you to take a peek?

Comment: @KJ as I mentioned, unfortunately, I cannot ask the source to recreate the PDF. If I will exhaust iText, I might try out OCR (have no idea where to start honestly). Thanks

Comment: @KJ, yes it is a foreign language (Hebrew). When I copy/paste, I am able to identify a pattern. However, extracting the data via the code, I don't get the same pattern. I am guessing it is related to encoding, but have no idea how to approach it... any idea?

Comment: @Yaniv *"May I send it over via email for you to take a peek?"* - yes, you can use the address in the about text of my account here.

Comment: Ok, I've had a look at the document you sent. The results of text extraction with iText are gibberish in two ways. On one hand there is text in Hebrew (as you mentioned before) and Arabic (I guess), both RTL scripts. iText text extraction is not aware of the specific writing direction of the text but always extracts LTR. You may use an internationalization component (like [ICU](https://icu.unicode.org/)) to get that sorted out. On the other hand there is lots and lots of seemingly structureless byte trash. But you get that, too, using Ctrl-A, Ctrl-C from Adobe Acrobat

Comment: @mkl, thank you for the time. So, I am guessing there isn't something I can do with the gibberish other than ask the source to recreate the PDF in some other way?

Comment: Well, if you get loads of files of this exact type again and again, it might be worthwhile for you to try and create a custom extractor based on e.g. iText, ICU, and a lot of own data analyzing code. Be aware, though, that that will require quite some time. The much better solution would be to have the source provide the data in a different, structured format, e.g. as csv or XML.